# <a4j:commandLink> is not working

Tags: jsf, richfaces

in my JSF 2.2 application I was trying to create an AJAX request using RichFaces 4.3.2 with .
The rendered HTML is:

```
<a href="#" id="x" name="x" onclick="RichFaces.ajax(x;,event,{x:x} );return false;">
```

The problem is that after clicking the link, nothing happens and an error in my Chrome Console appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'ajax'
```

When I type RichFaces into console I get some autocomplete possibilities like `Event, valueOf' etc. but it doesn't see any specific RichFaces functions. 
It looks like the RichFaces library wouldn't be attached at all but I have no idea why.

Why is it happening?

The code of the commandLink:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{commonsOperations.newsList}" var="n">
     <li>
         <a4j:commandLink action="#{commonsOperations.setSelectedNews(n)}"
            value="#{n.title}" render="content" />
     </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

I found out the problem why RichFaces libraries were not loaded properly was the conflict between RichFaces and PrimeFaces. After removing PrimeFaces from POM, all RichFaces javascript files are loaded.

Comment: add your actual commandlink code

Comment: Please review [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2118656/1065197) and find the reasons about your `<a4j:commandLink>` not being executed. If none applies, explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: Are you mixing multiple RichFaces versions/JARs in your webapp?